# Scrolling not working in NestedScrollView Android while using onClick on Linear Layout

Tags: android, android-layout, material-design, android-support-library, nestedscrollview

I have multiple included layouts in a single NestedScrollView. But when i am going to scroll, the included part not scrolling. And i load this layout in main layout which have CoordinatorLayout. So what is going wrong i can't understand. Below is my code,There are onClick events in all included layouts When i am removing my Linear Layout's on click events its working fine.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingBottom="20dp"
        android:paddingLeft="20dp"
        android:paddingTop="20dp">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:background="@color/AppPrimary"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="20dp"
            android:text="Demo"
            android:textColor="@color/white" />

        <include
            layout="@layout/layout1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="60dp" />

        <include
            android:id="@+id/layout2"
            layout="@layout/layout2" />

        <include
            layout="@layout/layout3"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="60dp" />

        <include
            android:id="@+id/layout3"
            layout="@layout/layout3" />

        <include
            layout="@layout/layout4"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="60dp" />

        <include
            android:id="@+id/layout5"
            layout="@layout/layout5" />

    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

Then below is my main activity code where this fragment will be append,

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:custom="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/main_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:id="@+id/appbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/scale_250dp"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

            <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
                android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                app:collapsedTitleTextAppearance="@style/CollapsedTitleTextAppearance"
                app:contentScrim="@color/AppPrimary"
                app:expandedTitleTextAppearance="@style/ExpandedTitleTextAppearance"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

         <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/img_placeholder"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:minHeight="100dp"
                    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                    android:src="@drawable/img_place_holder"
                    app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
                    app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways|enterAlwaysCollapsed" />
              <View
                    android:id="@+id/img_shadow"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:background="@drawable/drop_shadow" />

                <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                    app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                    app:navigationIcon="@drawable/ic_home"
                    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/img_slider"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="right"
                        android:padding="@dimen/scale_20dp"
                        android:src="@drawable/ic_navigation" />
                </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
            </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />


    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/scale_200dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:background="@color/AppPrimary"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="@color/AppPrimaryDark"
        android:dividerHeight="@dimen/scale_1dp"
        android:headerDividersEnabled="false"
        android:listSelector="@drawable/selector_background_listview"
        android:overScrollMode="never"
        android:scrollbars="none" />
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: What type of layout are your included views? Are they scroll container too?

Comment: No, they have Linear Layout as their parent view.@ThomasR.

Comment: Do you want to scroll the input of the includes or the whole view? And something in the including layout gaining the focus or touch event?

Comment: I want scroll only in this NestedScrollView area. Yes, there are touch event on this linear layouts. So, it may cause any defect in scrolling ? @ThomasR.

Comment: Of course it can. If you are overriding onDispatchTouchEvent or onTouchEvent and then return true on the included view, the event is consumed and will not be propagated to parent views.

Comment: But i have put onClick event not onTouch event. @ThomasR.

Comment: Ok, could you please append you code of the Java class and one example of an include?

Comment: @RonakJoshi do you have find a solution for this problem?

Comment: Not got any proper solution but if you give fixed size into your main layout where you including about 700dp then it will get height and work properly. @Zenco